# How to upload image in CKEDITOR with a Django backend?

Tags: javascript, html, django, ckeditor, image-uploading

I have done proper research of many image plugins which upload images to server using php scripts.I just want to know a proper way to upload images to a django-based server.

Here's I think what a approach should be -

On clicking a toolbar button,a dialog will be opened.UI elements of the dialog will include a form with a file type,two fields for height and width and a button (upload to server).On adding a image file and fields and clicking upload button,ajax call will be sent (am i right here? or form submit should handle it.) to the server where a particular view will handle saving image to a specified folder.

On success server will return the full path of the image and dialog will insert in the editor.

Sorry if my question is very naive but I just wanted to know if my assumptions are right before starting off.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Django package

```
https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor
```

This comes with a demo app. I would advise to look into that, and see how it works.

Basically you will have to configure the media url and there is a setting for ckeditor where to upload the media. Ckeditor will handle the image upload for you.

Uploaded content will be show in an overview page, where you will have the option "use image in text"

Comment: thanks for the reference to django-ckeditor.I read full code of django-ckeditor and merged its functionality in mine. Thanks